# Calculate computed columns during ETL or during insert to data warehouse

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-warehouse, etl

I was hoping someone could point me to some best practices regarding when to calculate a computed value which is stored in a data warehouse.

Consider the following example,

```
CREATE TABLE
(
    MyFactID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    OrderDimID INT NOT NULL, -- FK To OrderDimension
    StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CompletedDate DATETIME NULL,
    ElapsedCalendarTimeInMinutes INT NULL,
    ElapsedBusinessTimeInMinutes INT NULL
)
```

In this example, Elapsed calendar time in minutes would be the time (in minutes) from Start to End date.  Then, our business time reflects the working time that was available during those calendar days.

Currently, we are calculating this during ETL and inserting both dates.  I'm wondering if this is the correct place to perform this operation.

Some other thoughts were to:

A) Use indexed views by only storing the start and end date in the fact table, then creating a view which calculates the elapsed time in minutes and has a computed column which uses a function to figure out the business days.

B) Use an After trigger to update the elapsed calendar time and business time after an insert occurs which inserts or updates the completed date to a non-null value.

I feel that this should be done in the DB so that if any changes are made to the end date or calculation of the business time, it would reflect.  Doing it during ETL seems like it would be prone to problems.

Any thoughts on this are appreciated!

**Update:** There are at least 6 columns determined in this way.  We have business minutes, hours, and days (days are 12 hours for *our* business); then we have client minutes, hours, and days (determined via lookup table for the client's working hours); then we have simply calendar minutes, hours, and days (though these are not being stored; only minutes).  Since this is a DW, I would have expected all the data to be present and not require calculation.  To me, it seems like more work to ensure the ETL is correct and applied everywhere than to create a view overtop of the base data to get the computed information.

Comment: Why would you do it in the DB? Once the data reaches the DB at the end of the ETL process, you shouldn't be modifying it - the only thing that changes data in the warehouse should be the ETL (which, incidentially, is why you don't typically need the DB to enforce constraints in a warehouse as well)

Comment: I would want to do it in the DB so that we only have to insert the minimal amount of information (eg, start and end datetimes) and have the rest be calculated consistently in the DB so that everywhere that business time is used will go thru the same function.  Using ETL forces us to ensure that loading all the tables use the same process, while creating a view overtop of the base data allows us to drop and recreate the view if logic changes.

Comment: "Using ETL forces us to ensure that loading all the tables use the same process" - I would argue this is a good thing, since you're enforcing rules. Views can be fine, but will not perform as well. You can also do the ETL inside the database as "ELT" (extract - load - transform).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way should be the best solution:

In your ETL proces (Let us supose that is [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) but you can extrapolate to other technologies):

1. create a [data flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141122.aspx) to copy table from your operational database to datawarehouse backstage.
2. Update your fact table with a [T-Sql task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139753.aspx). A [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement should be enough:

Merge sample:

```
MERGE Target AS T
USING Source AS S
ON ( __  matching criteria ___) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT( OrderDimID, startDate, ... ) VALUES( ... )
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.ElapsedCalendarTimeInMinutes = ___some calculations___
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE (?)
```

This avoid triggers and indexed views.

Comment: I will look into this approach, but why do we want to avoid views / triggers (just curious)?

Comment: I avoid triggers all time I can: not easy to debug and also you should remember all times about it existence. About views, in a datamart I prefer to be all data materialized, more quick to make new indexes, joins, searches, ... . I don't know if they are 'write rules' about this but this, just is as I work and for me runs.

Comment: I marked this as the accepted answer, but have not explored the solution.  From the replies, it seems that is a reasonable solution.

Comment: Hi @user652688. Ok, come back with your final solution some day!

Comment: Is your suggestion that step 2 occur within the backstage (I'd call it a staging database) followed by an unspoken step 3: copy to the "real" warehouse table?

Answer (score 0):

You could use computed columns, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.100).aspx.  There are two flavors, non persisted and persisted.  Non persisted runs the calculation when you query the data.  Persisted stores the values on insert and then updates based on changes to the underlying formula data.  For a data warehouse application, I would recommend persisted.